# setter and getter as objc_setAssociatedObjec

Tags: objective-c, associated-object

I do not understand what mean this style and are there any benefits for standard setter/getter?

```
- (UIViewController*)myVC {
return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kMJPopupViewController);
}

- (void)setMyVC:(UIViewController *) myVC {
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kMyVC, myVC, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks, I find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have member variables -- which back "standard" properties' getters and setters -- in the main `@interface` and in the class extension (the category with no name). Using associated objects is especially useful in a class's category because it lets you pretend the class has a backing variable anyway.

See also [libextobjc](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc), which has a [synthesizeAssociation() macro](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTSynthesize.h), which makes it near trivial to add @properties inside categories.